# Pass function from props to render function in react

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Hi guys I have this code, I have add a table to it

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Auth from '../modules/Auth';
import Dashboard from '../components/Dashboard.jsx';
import {
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableHeader,
  TableHeaderColumn,
  TableRow,
  TableRowColumn,
} from 'material-ui/Table';


class DashboardPage extends React.Component {

  /**
   * Class constructor.
   */
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      secretData: '',
      selected: [1]
    };
  }

componentDidMount() {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('get', '/api/dashboard');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        // set the authorization HTTP header
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `bearer ${Auth.getToken()}`);
        xhr.responseType = 'json';
        xhr.addEventListener('load', () => {
          if (xhr.status === 200) {
            this.setState({
              secretData: xhr.response.message
            });
          }
        });
        xhr.send();
        isSelected = (index) => {
        return this.state.selected.indexOf(index) !== -1;
        };
        handleRowSelection = (selectedRows) => {
        this.setState({
          selected: selectedRows,
         });
        };
      }

  /**
```

I have pass the data like this, is this right

```
   */
  render() {
    return (<Dashboard isSelected={this.isSelected} handleRowSelection={this.handleRowSelection} />);
  }

}

    export default DashboardPage;
```

and this is the other code

```
  import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
import { Card, CardTitle, CardText } from 'material-ui/Card';
import {Table,TableBody,TableHeader,TableHeaderColumn,TableRow,TableRowColumn,} from 'material-ui/Table';



const Dashboard = ({handleRowSelection, isSelected }) => (
<Table onRowSelection={this.handleRowSelection}>
        <TableHeader>
          <TableRow>
            <TableHeaderColumn>ID</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn>Name</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn>Status</TableHeaderColumn>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHeader>
        <TableBody>
          <TableRow selected={this.isSelected(0)}>
            <TableRowColumn>1</TableRowColumn>
            <TableRowColumn>John Smith</TableRowColumn>
            <TableRowColumn>Employed</TableRowColumn>
          </TableRow>
          <TableRow selected={this.isSelected(1)}>
            <TableRowColumn>2</TableRowColumn>
            <TableRowColumn>Randal White</TableRowColumn>
            <TableRowColumn>Unemployed</TableRowColumn>
          </TableRow>
          <TableRow selected={this.isSelected(2)}>
            <TableRowColumn>3</TableRowColumn>
            <TableRowColumn>Stephanie Sanders</TableRowColumn>
            <TableRowColumn>Employed</TableRowColumn>
          </TableRow>
          <TableRow selected={this.isSelected(3)}>
            <TableRowColumn>4</TableRowColumn>
            <TableRowColumn>Steve Brown</TableRowColumn>
            <TableRowColumn>Employed</TableRowColumn>
          </TableRow>
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
);


export default Dashboard;
```

what I want is to pass the function isSelected, handleRowSelection to the other side but I have that problem tell me that Uncaught ReferenceError: isSelected is not defined what I want is to apply this http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/table 
is there is a way I can pass that function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in `DashboardPage`, you need to define `isSelected` and `handleRowSelection` as methods (or alternatively class properties).

Second, you need to drop `this.` everywhere in the `Dashboard` component.

And third, you need to use the `isSelected` callbacks in `Dashboard` like so: `() => isSelected(0)`. This will make sure `isSelected` is called after you actually select a table row. Currently, `isSelected` will get called 4 times right after the `Dashboard` component mounts, because the function is invoked directly.

BTW To be honest, I recommend you take some online course on ES6 and basics of React, otherwise you won't know what you're doing and why something works the way it does.

Answer (score 0):

Changes:

1- Dashboard is a Stateless Functional Component, so no `this` keyword.

2- You are destructuring only one arguments and ignoring all other, here:

```
const Dashboard = ({handleRowSelection }) => (.....)
```

3- `isSelected` is not defined inside `DashboardPage` component.

**Solutions:**

**1-** Avoid destructuring, and write it like this:

```
const Dashboard = (props) => ( 

)
```

And replace:

```
this.handleRowSelection` by `props.handleRowSelection
this.isSelected[0]` by `props.isSelected[0]
```

**2-** Or destructure other props values also:

```
const Dashboard = ({handleRowSelection, isSelected }) => (....)
```

And use them directly by `handleRowSelection` and `isSelected`.

Comment: still not working  const Dashboard = (props) => (
<Table onRowSelection={props.handleRowSelection}> and in the main file   constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      secretData: '',
      selected: [1]
    };

    isSelected = (index) => {
    return this.state.selected.indexOf(index) !== -1;
    };
    handleRowSelection = (selectedRows) => {
    this.setState({
      selected: selectedRows,
     });
    };
  }

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: isSelected is not defined

Comment: still the same error   render() {
    return (<Dashboard isSelected={this.state.isSelected} handleRowSelection={props.handleRowSelection} />);
  }

Comment: because you didn't define the `isSelected` in parent, first defined it inside state variable, state contains only two property: `secretData: '', selected: [1]` from where you are getting `isSelected`?

Comment: class DashboardPage extends React.Component {

  /**
   * Class constructor.
   */
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      secretData: '',
      selected: [1]
    };

    isSelected = (index) => {
    return this.state.selected.indexOf(index) !== -1;
    };
    handleRowSelection = (selectedRows) => {
    this.setState({
      selected: selectedRows,
     });
    };
  }